# Register generic page base class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, web-config, resharper

I create my own generic page base class:

```
public abstract class ViewPageBase<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    public ParamBuilder<TModel> Param { get { return new ParamBuilder<TModel>(Model); } }
}
```

Web.config:

```xml
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="ViewPageBase">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

This entry causes the following errors:

> INCORRECT_TYPE_PARAMETER_NUMBER

And

> An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

How do I register a generic page base class with ASP.NET MVC4 without using the `@inherits` keyword in each Razor view?

Comment: I'm not able to repro your errors. It's working fine with the generic basepage... when do you get the mentioned error on every page? Can you post a sample view and the full error messages with the stacktraces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. The error you are getting is not related to the custom view page.

Comment: No, I don't work with Resharper. Nor any other plugin in VS. Barebone VS installation.