# How to stop INCORRECT_TYPE_PARAMETER_NUMBER error by Resharper 8.2.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resharper, web-config

I'm getting this error from Resharper when I add abstract generic class in

```
<configuration>
    <system.web.webPages.razor>
        <pages pageBaseType="LegalAudit.Web.WebViewPageBase">
   ...
```

And the class:

```
public abstract class WebViewPageBase<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    // ...
}
```

It reappears from time to time after making "Ignore this error" in the error list. How to get rid of it totally?

(There is a linked question at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711959/register-generic-page-base-class) but it is not connected to resharper.)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried: `LegalAudit.Web.WebViewPageBase``1` or `LegalAudit.Web.WebViewPageBase``1[[LegalAudit.Web.ModelBase]]` Argh! so one backtick `, instead of two. But SO won't allow me to get that syntaxhighlighted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Register generic page base class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711959/register-generic-page-base-class)

Comment: @jessehouwing Nop, that doesn't work. And I've tried `LegalAudit.Web.WebViewPageBase&lt;TModel&gt;` and it breaks with "CS1514: { expected" at ` public class _Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml : LegalAudit.Web.WebViewPageBase<TModel><dynamic>`. So far I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @derigel That's different. Wrote above why.

Comment: @Artjom, error the same, solution is not. It's definitely ReSharper's error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Making another non generic class solved the error:

```
public abstract class WebViewPageBase<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    // ...
}

public abstract class WebViewPageBase : WebViewPageBase<object>
{

}
```

Comment: Could someone explain this... maybe link me to something to read, Thanks

Comment: This doesn't work in all the views I get Severity Code Description Project : Error CS0103 The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current among many other errors related to the custom extended base class. Not only that but I am unable to publish because of these errors

Answer (score 2):

When I add the following to the web.config, the error goes away, as expected. Reshaper, correctly, wants you to specify a specific implementation of `WebViewPageBase`:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="MvcApplication1.WebViewPageBase`1[[TModel]]">
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

And

```
namespace MvcApplication1
{
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    public abstract class WebViewPageBase<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yet it didn't help. All views broke with R# errors like "Argument type '...ViewModel' is not assignable to model type 'TModel'" and compilation errors like: "public class _Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml : ....Web.WebViewPageBase<>[[TModel]]<dynamic>". And BTW ildasm shows the class like `MvcApplication1.WebViewPageBase`1<TModel>`.

Comment: Which makes sense, since `TModel` isn't the same thign as `...ViewModel`. The following should again work: MvcApplication1.WebViewPageBase`1[[MvcAppliation1.YourBaseViewModel]].

Comment: I don't have the base class. I've tried with an interface which some views inherit from and it didn't help (the error above). Anyway I don't have any constraints for `TModel` in the `WebViewPageBase` so this doesn't look good solution. 

UPDATE. And it doesn't work for `..[[System.Object]]`.